# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{6^k}{(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})(3^{k}-2^{k})}= \text{rational number}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have been trying to solve the equation below for a while now without using the remainder rule.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{6^k}{(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})(3^{k}-2^{k})} = \text{ rational number}$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{6^k}{(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})(3^{k}-2^{k})}\Huge ?$$

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos I like the huge question mark.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos  Yes.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Use the telescoping sum

$$\frac{6^k}{(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})(3^k-2^k)}=\frac{2^k}{(3^k-2^k)}-\frac{2^{k+1}}{(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}$$

Comment: @MXVMXY I thought a telescoping sum was defined "A sum in which subsequent terms cancel each other, leaving only initial and final terms" [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)_italic_ **bold** 'code'

Comment: @Jon In infinite series, not just the first and last. See Wikipedia's Example of a telescoping sum, seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series.

Comment: @Jon Use telescoping to simplify $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{6^k}{(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})(3^{k}-2^{k})}$$. Then take the $n$ to infinity.

Comment: @MXVMXY The wiki only makes references to polynomials but not exponentials.  Meaning if a polynomial existed in the top part of the equation.

Comment: @Jon That means that it does work when there is a polynomial, not that it doesn't work when there isn't a polynomial. Exponentials work too. For example, it is correct to say that $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}-\frac{1}{2^{k}})=1$$

Comment: @Jon By assuming that it doesn't work for exponentials you are making the false assumption that $a$ is $b$ implies not $a$ is not $b$.